# Showing clicked li and hiding original

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a drop down list consisting several item.

Now hat i want is when we click And a drop down appears. Now when we click on any option in dropdown, the original should get replaced by clicked.

For eg : Original is `And`, now in drop down if we click `Not And`, then `And` should get replaced by `Not And` and so on.

Can someone please me out with it.

Thanks

Comment: Always include the relevant code **in the question**, don't just link. Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$('.click-nav .js ul li').click(function (e) {
    $(this).parent().prev().html($(this).html())
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/H52qs/)

Comment: Just what i was looking for. Thanks. Have to wait for 8 min to accept it is answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** to get and set the html content of an element:

```
$('.clicker li').click(function (e) {
    $('.clicker .hello').html($(this).html())
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3CSMW/11/)**